# Saving logs with log4net to a remote location when it is down slows down the application

Tags: c#, wpf, log4net

I save logs in shared folder in a remote server. When the remote server is brought down, it slows down the application.

How do i fix it?

Comment: That's too bad. Do you want to ask question?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find the root cause

Comment: When you profile the application, what's the actual bottleneck?  Presumably "how to fix it" is to log to known reliable locations.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: The application probably doesn't know if the remote server has gone down or if it's just a slow network connection. Why don't you cache the logs locally and upload to the remote server periodically?

Comment: Don't have enough space to log locally. My application updates the UI based on the response received from the service. When the LOG (remote) server is brought down, the user interface goes non-responsive for few seconds and there is a delay in getting response from the server.

Comment: I suggest you use an asynchronous forwarding logger, eg https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async